# Python 3 Pandas How to extract a string between two '_', with error handling in a DF?

Tags: python-3.x, string, extract

This question is relatively close to existing answers about extracting strings, but my data has technical twists to it.  The df column data looks like this:

```
Col1:
2909_10_2018
2909_14_2019
32_13_2019
4200_14_2018
4124__2019
```

Objective is to extract the string between the two "_", except sometimes there is no string.

I tried multiple solutions posted in similar topics to no avail:

```
try:
   df['Col2'] = re.search('.*abc_[^_]*', df.Col1)
except:
   TypeError:
   df['Col2'] = ''
```

Produces ""

```
try:
   df['Col2'] = re.search('_(.*)_', df.Col1)
except:
   TypeError:
   df['Col2'] = ''
```

Produces ""

```
df['Col2'] = df.Col1.str.split("_", n = 1, expand = True)
```

Results in ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1.

What is a good pythonic way to extract the text between the "_" while handling the omissions?

Comment: so in case of empty string, you want the entire value to be added?

Comment: Hi Naveen, for the empty string, a ' ' or null would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the format doesn't change, you can use `lambda` function as you have to do the same operation for each and every row. The below code will create a new column with empty strings as well.

**Code:**

```
df['Col2'] = df.Col1.apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
```

**Output:**

```
    Col1           Col2
0   2909_10_2018    10
1   2909_14_2019    14
2   32_13_2019      13
3   4200_14_2018    14
4   4124__2019
```

Comment: I need to brush up on my lambdas but yes this is exactly what I needed.  The blanks are nulls which is fine.